# I want Print an array in reverse but it is not printing all the elements of the array

Tags: arrays, c, loops, for-loop, reverse

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main()

 {
 int a,n,i;
 int arr[n];
// int arr[]={1,4,3,2};
scanf("%d",&n);
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
}
for(int i=n;i>=0;i--)
{
    printf("%d ",arr[i]);
}
}
```

Thanks guys for helping in that but now what could be the error its showing garbage value.

Comment: `i>=arr[0]` is unusual here. I suspect you want `i >= 0`.

Comment: Some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) would help in explaining why not all elements are printed.

Comment: Also, if you would print "normally" and not in reverse, would you really use `i <= arr[3]`? Or would you use `i <= 3` (or possibly `i < 4`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the defined array

```
int arr[]={1,4,3,2};
```

in this for loop

```
for(int i=3;i>=arr[0];i--)
```

`i` equal to 0 is not greater than or equal to `arr[0]` equal to `1`. So the condition of the loop `i>=arr[0]` evaluates to logical false when `i` is equal to `0`.

Maybe actually you mean the following loop

```
for(int i=3;i >=0;i--)
```

Pay attention to that it is not a good idea to use magic numbers like `3`.

You could define the loop the following way

```
for ( size_t i = sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr ); i != 0; --i )
{
    printf( "%d ", arr[i - 1] );
}
```

or

```
for ( size_t i = sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr ); i != 0; )
{
    printf( "%d ", arr[--i] );
}
```

Also in your commented statements are placed in a wrong order

```
int a,n;
//int arr[n];
//scanf("%d",&n);
```

At first you need to read a positive value in the variable `n` and only after that to declare the variable length array `arr`

```
int a,n;
scanf("%d",&n);
int arr[n];
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    size_t n;

    if ( scanf( "%zu", &n ) == 1 && n != 0 )
    {
        int arr[n];

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
        {
            scanf( "%d", arr + i );
        }

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", arr[i] );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );

        for ( size_t i = n; i != 0; i-- )
        {
            printf( "%d ", arr[i-1] );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter the following values

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
```

then the program output will be

```
1 2 3 4 5 
5 4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As arr[0] contains 1 your code will only print arr[3], arr[2] and arr[1].

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
int main ()
{
  int a, n;
//int arr[n];
  int arr[] = { 1, 4, 3, 2 };
//scanf("%d",&n);
  for (int i = sizeof (arr) / sizeof (arr[0]) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      printf ("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

sizeof gives size of type (for int in c size is 4)
so you can divide it by any one element of the array
then your iterator variable i's value is also dynamic.

Comment: why did you do -1?

Comment: why couldnt be it put without -1

Comment: arrays are indexed from 0 to length-1

Answer (score 0):

Need to tweak condition in for loop to `i = n -1` while printing reverse array.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting garbage values because your second for loop tries to print arr[n] which is out of bounds. Array indexing goes from 0 to n-1 where n is the size of the array. [Ref](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-to-arrays/)

Here is the corrected code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 int a,n,i;
 int arr[n];
 // int arr[]={1,4,3,2};
 scanf("%d",&n);
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
 }
 for(int i=n;i>0;i--)
 {
    printf("%d ",arr[i-1]);
 }
 return 0;
}
```